# Convert the column to same type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframes. However, when I use read_csv function in pandas, the output of date column are different. I try to use df.astype(object) function to convert that column to object but doesnt works. I could not merge these 2 dataframe because the expiryDate column is different.

df1:

```
symbol.  expiryDate.
AA       20/5/2021
```

df2:

```
symbol.  expiryDate.
AA       2021-05-20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the column to `datetime dtype` using `to_datetime`, and then proceed to merge the dataframes.

```
df1['expiryDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['expiryDate'], format="%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Specifying the datetime format is optional, but I suggest that you use it to avoid possible wrongly converted dates.

Comment: You 're welcome.